# Python; Object is not defined error, i tought i defined it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, server-sent-events, openai-api

I am new to python and cant find a working solution therefore i am asking you for help

This is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import sseclient

API_KEY = 'Hidden for reasons'

def performRequestWithStreaming():
    reqUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
    reqHeaders = {
        'accept':   'text/event-stream',
        'authorization':    'bearer ' + API_KEY
    }
reqBody = {
    "model":    "text-davinci-003",
    "prompt":   "what is python",
    "maxtokens":    100,
    "temperature":  0,
    "stream":   True,
}
request = requests.post(reqUrl, stream=True, headers=reqHeaders, json=reqbody)
client = sseclient.SSEClient(request)
for event in client.events():
    if event.data != 'DONE':
        print(json.loads(event.data)['choices'][0]['text'], end="", flush=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    performRequestWithStreaming()
```

I am getting the error:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'reqUrl' is not defined
  File bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    request = requests.post(reqUrl, stream=True, headers=reqHeaders, json=reqbody)
NameError: name 'reqUrl' is not defined
```

tried defining it again, or at the top, tried different commands in the requests api, or creating them as an object, it didnt work

Comment: Indent lines 13 to 24.

Comment: Starting with the `reqBody = {` line, the lines of code are **not** indented, so they are **not** part of the `performRequestWithStreaming` function.

Comment: I highly recommend you use an IDE so you can debug your code better. The problem in your code is reqUrl variable is under the performRequestWithStreaming function which is out of the scope when you access the variable. For example, the API_KEY variable is global scope but reqUrl is function scope. I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to indent where it says `reqBody...` to the `print(json.loa...` one level higher.

Correct code:

```py
import requests
import json
import sseclient

API_KEY = 'Hidden for reasons'

def performRequestWithStreaming():
    reqUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
    reqHeaders = {
        'accept':   'text/event-stream',
        'authorization':    'bearer ' + API_KEY
    }
    reqBody = {
        "model":    "text-davinci-003",
        "prompt":   "what is python",
        "maxtokens":    100,
        "temperature":  0,
        "stream":   True,
    }
    request = requests.post(reqUrl, stream=True, headers=reqHeaders, json=reqbody)
    client = sseclient.SSEClient(request)
    for event in client.events():
        if event.data != 'DONE':
            print(json.loads(event.data)['choices'][0]['text'], end="", flush=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    performRequestWithStreaming()
```

Comment: Also note that it matters if the white spaces are spaces or tabs or mixed (!). I've came across files in my career where the white spaces were mixed, caused indentation problem although one couldn't spot it by simply looking at the source code

Answer (score 0):

pyhton doesn't use { } to represent a block of code rather it makes use of indentation and in your program since

request = requests.post(reqUrl, stream=True, headers=reqHeaders, json=reqbody)
is present without indentation it is called first instead of of the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why you think it is going to work. It should be obvious that the variable `reqUrl` is on a lower level than the variable `request` and thus it is impossible for the code to work. You have made a odd choice defining one variable in a function. You will have to global the variable `reqUrl` or define the whole code in the function `performRequestWithStreaming()`.
Since you are trying to use

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    performRequestWithStreaming()
```

It will be better to just put all the code in the same function.
Here is the corrected code:

```py
import requests
import json
import sseclient

API_KEY = 'Hidden for reasons'

def performRequestWithStreaming():
    reqUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions'
    reqHeaders = {
        'accept':   'text/event-stream',
        'authorization':    'bearer ' + API_KEY
    }
    reqBody = {
        "model":    "text-davinci-003",
        "prompt":   "what is python",
        "maxtokens":    100,
        "temperature":  0,
        "stream":   True,
    }
    request = requests.post(reqUrl, stream=True, headers=reqHeaders, json=reqbody)
    client = sseclient.SSEClient(request)
    for event in client.events():
        if event.data != 'DONE':
            print(json.loads(event.data)['choices'][0]['text'], end="", flush=True)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    performRequestWithStreaming()
```